# Convert Vector of Objects to Strings to add to a column in a For Loop in R

Tags: r

What I want to do is create a column in the gamelog data frame that assigns the goalie name from the Goalies vector to the column

Is there any way to do this?

I heard of deparse(substitute()) but when I use it, it doesn't work in my for loop

```
library(XML)

Howard<-'http://naturalstattrick.com/playerreport.php?fromseason=20182019&thruseason=20182019&stype=2&sit=5v5&stdoi=oi&rate=n&v=g&playerid=8470657'


Lehner<-'http://naturalstattrick.com/playerreport.php?fromseason=20182019&thruseason=20182019&stype=2&sit=5v5&stdoi=oi&rate=n&v=g&playerid=8475215'

Binnington<-'http://naturalstattrick.com/playerreport.php?fromseason=20182019&thruseason=20182019&stype=2&sit=5v5&stdoi=oi&rate=n&v=g&playerid=8476412'

Goalies<-c(Howard, Lehner, Binnington)

gamelog<-data.frame()

   for(goalie in Goalies){
   goaliehtml<-readHTMLTable(goalie)
   goaliedata<-goaliehtml[['gamelog']]
   goaliedata$player<-deparse(substitute(goalie))
   gamelog<-rbind(gamelog, goaliedata)
}
```

I want goaliedata$player to be equal to the goalie that is being ran through the for loop

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this differently. First, I'd store the player names and IDs in a list or data frame. For example:

```
player_id <- data.frame(player = c("Howard", "Lehner", "Binnington"), 
                        id = c(8470657, 8475215, 8476412),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  player          id
1 Howard     8470657
2 Lehner     8475215
3 Binnington 8476412
```

Next, I would write a function which takes `player`and `id` and returns the data frame of data from the website with the player name column added.

My function uses the `rvest` library, which supplies `read_html` and `html_table`, instead of `XML`. There's a complication: missing values are represented by `-`, which turns a column into characters. But not all players have missing values, so those columns are numeric. So the function changes `-` to `NA`, then converts all values to numeric before combining the players. The `dplyr` library supplies the `mutate` functions.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

get_player_data <- function(player, id) {
  base_url <- "http://naturalstattrick.com/playerreport.php?fromseason=20182019&thruseason=20182019&stype=2&sit=5v5&stdoi=oi&rate=n&v=g&playerid="
  paste0(base_url, id) %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_table(header = TRUE) %>% 
    .[[1]] %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-starts_with("Game"), -starts_with("Team")), 
              funs(as.numeric(gsub("-", NA, .)))) %>% 
    mutate(player = player)
}
```

Now we can go through each player + id. Rather than a loop we can use `pmap_df` from the `purrr` library. This takes each player + id, sends it to our function and combines the outputs into a single data frame at the end:

```
library(purrr)
player_data <- pmap_df(player_id, get_player_data)
```

For your 3 example players, this returns a data frame of 83 rows and 52 columns, with the player name in the last column.

Note: it's assumed all player data has the same form as the 3 examples (52 columns, missing values represented by `-`). If not, the function will probably give errors.

Answer (score 0):

`goalie` doesn't contain the name of the goalie. So first you to give the vector `Goalies` also the names of the goalie.

```
library(XML)

Howard<-'http://naturalstattrick.com/playerreport.php?fromseason=20182019&thruseason=20182019&stype=2&sit=5v5&stdoi=oi&rate=n&v=g&playerid=8470657'

Lehner<-'http://naturalstattrick.com/playerreport.php?fromseason=20182019&thruseason=20182019&stype=2&sit=5v5&stdoi=oi&rate=n&v=g&playerid=8475215'

Binnington<-'http://naturalstattrick.com/playerreport.php?fromseason=20182019&thruseason=20182019&stype=2&sit=5v5&stdoi=oi&rate=n&v=g&playerid=8476412'

Goalies<-c(Howard, Lehner, Binnington)
# give the vector the names of the goalies
names(Goalies) <- c("Howard", "Lehner", "Binnington")

gamelog<-data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(Goalies)) {
  goaliehtml<-readHTMLTable(Goalies[i])
  goaliedata<-goaliehtml[['gamelog']]
  goaliedata$player<-names(Goalies[i])
  gamelog<-rbind(gamelog, goaliedata)
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have about 60 goalies in the 'Goalies' vector, so I am not trying to type every goalies name in 'names(Goalies)<-c('Howard', 'Leh.......)'     I was hoping to use something along the lines of substitute(deparse(x))

Comment: I noticed on the webpage there is a pull downlist with goalie names. Maybe you can get that one and then you have all your goalie names and id's.